# Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Getting an error while runtime how to resolve this plz help me out with as i am stucked in it i am a beginner

getting log cat error 
Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/signInText"
            android:background="@drawable/facebook_connect"
             />
```

Home Activity

```
package com.styllonz.activities;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.styllonz.R;
import com.styllonz.fragments.ForgotPasswordFragment;
import com.styllonz.fragments.LandingFragment;
import com.styllonz.fragments.LoginFragment;
import com.styllonz.fragments.SignUpFragment;
import com.styllonz.models.Response;
import com.styllonz.network.BusNetworkCallback;
import com.styllonz.network.WebserviceApi;
import com.styllonz.utils.Constants;
import com.styllonz.utils.Utilities;

import retrofit.RetrofitError;


public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LandingFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,SignUpFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        LoginFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, ForgotPasswordFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener


{


    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /* A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents
     * us from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress, mSignInClicked;

    ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

     ProgressDialog progress;

    Context mContext;

    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
            replaceFragment(LandingFragment.newInstance(), LandingFragment.TAG, false);

        mSharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        mEditor=mSharedPreferences.edit();


        mContext=this;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();



    }


    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag, boolean addToBackstack) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (addToBackstack)
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.flFragmentHolder, fragment, fragmentTag).addToBackStack("")
                    .commit();
        else
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.flFragmentHolder, fragment, fragmentTag)
                    .commit();

    }


    @Override
    public void onHomeFragmentInteraction(View view) {
        int viewId = view.getId();


        switch (viewId) {
            case R.id.cfbSignUp:

                replaceFragment(SignUpFragment.newInstance(), SignUpFragment.TAG, true);

                break;
            case R.id.cfbLogin:

                replaceFragment(LoginFragment.newInstance(), LoginFragment.TAG, true);

                break;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onSignUpFragmentInteraction(View view) {


        int viewId = view.getId();

        switch (viewId) {


            case R.id.cftvSignUpTitle:
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();


        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginFragmentInteraction(View view) {

        int viewId = view.getId();

        switch (viewId) {
            case R.id.cftvForgotPassword:
                replaceFragment(ForgotPasswordFragment.newInstance(), ForgotPasswordFragment.TAG, true);
                break;
            case R.id.cfbLogin:

                Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
                finish();

                break;

            case R.id.cftvLoginTitle:
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();


        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate())
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onForgotPasswordFragmentInteraction(View view) {

        int viewId = view.getId();

        switch (viewId) {

            case R.id.cftvForgotPasswordTitle:
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();

        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    //
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mSignInClicked = false;
        //   Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        getProfileInformation();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {

            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                    0).show();

            if(progress!=null&&progress.isShowing())
                progress.dismiss();

            return;

        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
            mConnectionResult = result;
            resolveSignInError();

        }

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,responseCode,intent);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Sign-in into google
     */
    public void signInWithGplus() {




        if(Utilities.isOnline(this)) {

            progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
                    "Loading...", true);
            if (!mSharedPreferences.contains(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_B_GMAIL_SOURCE)||!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mSignInClicked = true;
                    if(mConnectionResult!=null)
                    resolveSignInError();
                    else
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            } else if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
                getProfileInformation();
            }
            else if (mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_B_GMAIL_SOURCE, false)) {
                login();
            }
            else {
                if(progress!=null)
                {
                    progress.dismiss();
                }
            }


        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please connect to internet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    /**
     * Method to resolve any signin errors
     */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
     */
    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {

                final Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();

                final String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                        + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                        + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

                final WebserviceApi webserviceApi=Utilities.getWebservice(mContext);

                if(webserviceApi!=null)

                {
                    webserviceApi.signupFromSource(email, personName, 'c', "google", "gmail", new BusNetworkCallback<Response>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Response obj) {

                            if (progress != null & progress.isShowing())
                                progress.dismiss();
                            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), " success");
                            if (obj.getResult() != null && obj.getResult().equals("success")) {//  Utilities.showAlertDialog(mContext,"Alert","User registered successfully.");
                                mEditor.putBoolean(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_B_GMAIL_SOURCE, true);
                                mEditor.putString(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_S_GMAIL_EMAIL, email);
                                mEditor.putString(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_S_GMAIL_EMAIL, currentPerson.getId());
                                mEditor.commit();

                                login();


                            } else if (obj.getError() != null && obj.getError().length() > 0) {

                                if (obj.getError().contains("Email")) {
                                    mEditor.putBoolean(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_B_GMAIL_SOURCE, true);
                                    mEditor.putString(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_S_GMAIL_EMAIL, email);
                                    mEditor.putString(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_S_GMAIL_EMAIL, currentPerson.getId());
                                    mEditor.commit();
                                    login();
                                } else {
                                    Utilities.showAlertDialog(mContext, "Error", obj.getError());
                                    {
                                        if (progress != null & progress.isShowing())
                                            progress.dismiss();

                                    }

                                }
                            } else {

                                Utilities.showAlertDialog(mContext, "Error", "Some error occured please try later");
                                {
                                    if (progress != null & progress.isShowing())
                                        progress.dismiss();

                                }

                            }

                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(RetrofitError error) {

                            if (progress != null & progress.isShowing())
                                progress.dismiss();
                            super.onFailure(error);

                        }
                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    if(progress!=null)
                    {
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                }



            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No information found from google", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(progress!=null&progress.isShowing())
                    progress.dismiss();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No information found from google", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(progress!=null&progress.isShowing())
                progress.dismiss();
        }

    }

    private void login() {
        WebserviceApi webserviceApi=Utilities.getWebservice(this);


        if(webserviceApi!=null) {

            if (mSharedPreferences.contains(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_S_GMAIL_EMAIL))

                webserviceApi.loginFromSource(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_S_GMAIL_EMAIL , Constants.SHARED_PREFS_S_GMAIL_ID,


                        new BusNetworkCallback<Response>() {


                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Response obj) {
                                progress.dismiss();

                                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), " success");
                                if (obj.getResult() != null && obj.getResult().equals("success")) {

                                    Constants.userDetails = obj.getData();

                                    Gson gson = new Gson();


                                    mEditor.putString(Constants.SHARED_PREFS_S_USER_DETAILS, gson.toJson(Constants.userDetails));

                                    mEditor.commit();

                                    Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(mainActivityIntent);
                                    finish();

                                } else if (obj.getError() != null && obj.getError().length() > 0)

                                    Utilities.showAlertDialog(mContext, "Error", obj.getError());

                                else

                                    Utilities.showAlertDialog(mContext, "Error", "Some error occurred. Please try again later.");

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(RetrofitError error) {

                                if(progress!=null&progress.isShowing())
                                    progress.dismiss();
                                super.onFailure(error);

                                Utilities.showAlertDialog(mContext, "Error", "Some error occurred. Please try again later.");


                            }
                        }


                );
        }
        else
        {
            if(progress!=null&progress.isShowing())
                progress.dismiss();

        }
    }


}
```